# JQuery multiple hover effects not working

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aboutme-block").hide();
    $("#stories-block").hide();

    $("div.aboutme").hover(function () {
        $("#aboutme-block").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#stories-block").hide();
    });

    $("div.stories").hover(function () {
        $("#stories-block").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#aboutme-block").hide();
    }); 
});
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? You should explain what you want it to do and what it actually does.

Comment: Could you post the associated HTML?

Comment: please ensure all your ids and class names are correct

Comment: @all : Well, I'm trying to set up my site http://rahul27.co.cc/ ... you can see that the 1st hover effect .. $("div.aboutme").hover(function () ... is working fine  but the second isn't.

Comment: also I'm new to JQuery programming but I can assure that the tags are right. Infact if I place the second hover function ..  $("div.stories").hover(function () { ... before the first it works fine. Im kind of having a feeling that I have got my syntax wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is, but I'd prevent animations from taking place unnecessarily.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#aboutme-block,#stories-block").hide();

  $("div.aboutme").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#aboutme-block:hidden").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#stories-block").stop(true,true).hide();
  });

  $("div.stories").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#stories-block:hidden").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#aboutme-block").stop(true,true).hide();
  }); 
});
```

Here's a shortened version that reuses the same handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var blocks = $("#aboutme-block,#stories-block").hide();

    $("div.aboutme,div.stories").mouseenter(function() {
        var isAboutme = $(this).hasClass('aboutme');
        blocks.eq(+(!isAboutme)).filter(":hidden").fadeIn(1000);
        blocks.eq(+(isAboutme)).stop(true, true).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ive tried the shortened version but its not working in my case.

Comment: @Rahul: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/xsZ9h/) using the shortened code.

Comment: . its still not working. The blocks aren't displayed. I kind of have a feeling that it may be one of the following reasons: 1) The blocks are defined as nodes in a Drupal Panel 2)Its a browser issue 3) A JQuery version issue 4) Possibility of an override script by Drupal 5) CSS override by Drupal.

Comment: @Rahul: Does the longer version on top work? Or do they all fail? Also, what version of jQuery is loaded? If you're not sure, do `alert($.fn.jquery);`. It will give you the version number.

Comment: . it worked ... I updated my JQuery to 1.3.2 and it now works fine .. in your example if you try running the same script with version 1.2.6 it does not work. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have `$("div.aboutme").hover ...`. Is this control being found?

Answer (score 1):

use `mouseover` instead of `hover`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#aboutme-block").hide();
  $("#stories-block").hide();

  $("div.aboutme").mouseover(function() {
    $("#aboutme-block").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#stories-block").hide();
  });

  $("div.stories").mouseover(function(){
    $("#stories-block").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#aboutme-block").hide();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: There is no big difference between those two. `hover` would just bind the handler to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` but that should not make a difference (actually it would be better to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`):

Comment: @elek , hover is better for some flickering issues and all , its same as your code

Comment: @Felix: There could be a conflict using `hover()` if you go right from a `div.aboutme` to `div.stories` within 1000ms. The `aboutme` handler will be trying to `fadeIn` the `#aboutme-block` while the `stories` handler will try to `hide()` it. Though, I'd agree about using `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`.

Comment: @patrick dw: Ok, I see, there could be timing issues. I mean I cannot imagine anyway that the OP wants the fade in also `mouseleave`. But we don't know what the actual problem is. It *could* be what you described but until we know for sure, the "solution" given here is not "better" (saying to remove all code and just do nothing would be an equally valid solution ;))

Comment: @Felix kling , lets ask rahul to post his original html

Comment: @Felix: You're right. It is all speculation at this point. The quality of the answers are going to be limited to that of the question. About all we can do is point out potential flaws in the given code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been solved. The problem was with the version of JQuery running. If you try running [patrick's example](http://jsfiddle.net/xsZ9h/10/) using version 1.2.6 it does not work. Using a higher version solves the problem. 
Thanks guys for all the help :)